# UITableView doesn't work for Arabic language cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I've built slide-out menu (UITableView) with SWRevealViewController and the menu contains Arabic strings, but the menu should reload a new data if pressed on some string;

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell
  if cell.label.text == "الرئيسية" {
        menuTitles = menuTitlesName
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
 }
```

it's doesn't do anything, I can't work with indexPath because the tableView will reload a new data, so any suggestions ?!

Comment: At where you are checking this condition ? please add some more code so we can help you further.

Comment: @Prince check out, edit !

Comment: `dequeueReusableCell` does not belongs to `didSelectRowAt` delegate method, you should use [`cellForRow(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow]) to get `existing` cell.

Comment: @user28434 so how should I get the pressed cell, could you please explain in code ?

Comment: @MohammadEliassAlhusain, `let cell = tableView(at: indexPath) as! WhateverYourCellClass`. Ok, link i posted in previous comment got corrupted, here's proper one: [`cellForRow(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get selected cell instance from cellForRowAtIndexPath  and then check your label text and reload data

```
let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell
if cell.label.text == "الرئيسية" {
    menuTitles = menuTitlesName
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Question has `swift3` tag, but your code is `swift2` like.